# JAVA Hangman Program revealing letter at a certain index, handling multiple instances of char in word

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
if (posOfGuessLetter == -1)
    {
        System.out.print("Your letter was not found in the 
        spaces provided");
    } //if
if (posOfGuessLetter == 0)
    {
        displayWordAsDashes = (guessLetter + 
        displayWordAsDashes.substring(posOfGuessLetter + 1));
        displayWord = 
        displayWordAsDashes.substring(posOfGuessLetter + 1);
    } //if
if (posOfGuessLetter == 9)
    {
    displayWordAsDashes = (displayWordAsDashes.substring(0, 
    posOfGuessLetter) + guessLetter);
    displayWord = (displayWordAsDashes.substring(0, 
    posOfGuessLetter));
    } //if
else
    {
        displayWordAsDashes = (displayWordAsDashes.substring(0, 
        posOfGuessLetter) + guessLetter + 
        displayWordAsDashes.substring(posOfGuessLetter + 1));
        displayWord = (displayWordAsDashes.substring(0, 
        posOfGuessLetter) + 
        (displayWordAsDashes.substring(posOfGuessLetter + 1)));
    }

while (displayWord.contains(guessLetter))
    {
        displayWordAsDashes = (displayWordAsDashes.substring(0, 
        posOfGuessLetter) + guessLetter + 
        displayWordAsDashes.substring(posOfGuessLetter + 1));
        displayWord = (displayWordAsDashes.substring(0, 
        posOfGuessLetter) + 
        (displayWordAsDashes.substring(posOfGuessLetter + 1)));
    } //while
    } //else
System.out.print("The updated word is: " + 
displayWordAsDashes);
```

I am trying to create a hangman program, and in this part it checks the index position of a user input for the character they want to find in the word and then removes the dash on that index and reveals the letter they just guessed. However, my program is not revealing both letters if the word has two of the same letter (i.e. naRRowing, lOOps) which is what I tried to program the while loop at the end to do. Can anyone tell me what I messed up on??

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see what error you did but both pos == 0 and pos == 9 are superfluous due to

```
aString.substring(aString.length());
```

and

```
aString.substring(0, 0);
```

both returning the empty string.

If you don't have to keep track of where the letter was you could do something like this:

```
private String wordToGuess = "hangman";
private String guessedSoFar = wordToGuess.replaceAll(".", "-");
private String leftToGuess = wordToGuess;

public String guess(char c) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < leftToGuess.length() ; i++) {
        if(leftToGuess.charAt(i) == c) {
            guessedSoFar = guessedSoFar.substring(0, i) + c + guessedSoFar.substring(i + 1);
        }
    }
    leftToGuess = leftToGuess.replace(c, '-');
    return guessedSoFar;
}
```